# Passing variables through if statements without new method

Tags: java

So well I'm just here wondering if there's a way to pass a variable through a statement. Something like this:

```
if (a < b) {
    double g = 1
} else if (a > b) {
    double g = 0
}
if (g = 1) {
    System.out.print("true");
} else {
    System.out.print("false");
}
```

Mainly saying, I want to set a variable if a statement is true or not, go to the next section of code and print out "true" or "false" and I pretty much am just wondering if this is possible without creating a new method (and of course if there is code for it).
Thank you.

Comment: You've got a scope problem.  You could just write something like `double g = a < b ? 1 : 0;` if that's what you want.

Comment: have you test your above code?

Comment: Oh, I read it as pseudo-code, not as Java.

Comment: Why do you want to compare the same thing twice? That's just complicating your code and wasting processing time: `if (a<b) { print("true"); } else { print("false"); }` is equivalent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. You have to declare `g` outside the `if` statements, so you can access to it whithin the whole function. Read more about *scopes*, if you declare a variable inside a block `{}`, it will be accessible just inside it, so when you declared it into the `if-else if` blocks, you couldn't access to the variable outside.

Also to compare a primitive type (in this case `double`) you have to use `==` operator, because `=` is used for assignment.

```
double g;
if (a<b) {
    g = 1;
}
else if (a>b) {
    g = 0;
}
// What happen if 'a = b'?

if (g == 1) {
    System.out.print("true");
}
else {
    System.out.print("false");
}
```

**Note:** What value will take `g` if `a == b`? You may want to take care about that case too.

Answer (score 1):

```
double g;
if (a<b) {
   g=1
}
else if (a>b) {
   g=0
}
if (g==1) {
    System.out.print("true");
}
else {
     System.out.print("false");
}
```

also make sure that you always use `==` instead of `=` in your if-statement

Answer (score 1):

The if condition `if (g=1)` does not work with java. This would work with C though.

You should code `if (g==1)` to test if g is in fact equal to the int value 1.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "would work with C".  In C, `if (g=1)` will always run the "true" branch.

Answer (score 0):

You've got three problems.

- `a` and `b` aren't defined.  Define them before entering the `if` statement.
- Define `g` outside of the `if` statement (a simple `double g;` will suffice), then set the values as part of your conditional logic.  You *do* have to give it a default value if you intend to keep the `else if` there, since Java would complain about that not being defined.
- `g=1` isn't going to work the way you think it should; you probably mean `g == 1`.

**With `else if`**

```
int a, b; // assumed instantiated with values
double g = -1; // required since Java can't guarantee that the else-if will be hit
if (a<b) {
    g = 1;
} else if (a>b) {
    g = 0;
}
```

**With `else`**

```
int a, b; // assumed instantiated with values
double g; // instantiation not required since Java can guarantee the else case
if (a<b) {
    g = 1;
} else {
    g = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  double g; double a = 4.0; double b = 3.0;
    if(a < b){
        g = 1.0;
    System.out.print("true");
    }
    else if (a > b){
        g = 0.0;
        System.out.print("false");
    }
    // Why not write your code like the above example. It seems like the    
    //same operations are executed but with less lines of code.
```